# How to call a page from custom AppBar using onPressed?

Tags: flutter

I have created a custom appBar in flutter MyApplicationBar.dart
I am including every page? now how to call Login Page   onPressed: () function

```
  class MyApplicationBar extends AppBar {
  MyApplicationBar({Key key, Widget title}) 
    : super(key: key, title:title, actions:<Widget>[
    IconButton(
        icon: new Icon(Icons.lock), 
        tooltip: 'Login',
        onPressed: () {
          print('sssss');

        },
      ),
    IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.supervised_user_circle),
              tooltip: 'Accounts',
              onPressed: () {



              },
            ),
  ]);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are more than one methods to navigate to new page 
1. Easy way is Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(routeName, arguments: arguments)

but the best approach is to use because it is very clean and increase code readability.
And this is how professional do Navigation.
2. using  onGenerateRoute in your MaterialApp Widget

```
return MaterialApp(
      // remove debug banner 
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: APP_NAME,
      home: Home(),
      onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
        switch (settings.name) {
        case "abc":
              return CupertinoPageRoute(
                builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  return VideoTopics();
                },
                settings: settings);
        break;
}});
```

Now to navigate from any page to abc page just use this line of code

```
   Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("abc");
```

make sure the text you are passing in Navigator is same to as in onGeneratedRoute 
so it is advisiable to use constants for such things